# Whis is faster - fetching array with mysqli prepared statement/with mysqli only

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Which is faster? Fetching array with mysqli prepared statement:

```
    $statement=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `name`,`age` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=?");
    $statement->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($array['0'],$array['1']);
    $statement->fetch();
    return $array;
```

Or fetching array with mysqli only:

```
return $mysqli->query("SELECT `name`,`age`FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$id."'")->fetch_row();
```

EDIT: **Use only prepared statements, because normal queries are NOT SAFE! Do not worry about performance - worry about security!**

EDIT2: **Recently I started using PDO instead of MySQLi. PDO is better than MySQLi extension in many ways. One of them is fetching and looping through a multidimensional array.**

Comment: "Better" and "faster" aren't the same thing. For "faster", you can find the answer easily by benchmarking your code.

Comment: Reversing my vote for the edits. You've got it right. (However, you can make an abstraction library out of mysqli too, even better than PDO - but that's take time)

Comment: How do I benefit from creating an abstract library and can you guide me with some resources I can read or some tips for creating such a 'thing'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a strict rule: bother yourself with performance questions only if you have strong reason to.
Otherwise you would either just waste your time or even make things worse.

In your particular case, a difference, even if exists, would be hardly noticeable.
So, it'sproper design should be your concern, not imaginable "performance issue".

Comment: @WesleyMurch this reads as a long comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DanielA.White I agree with you but the question itself is nonsense and this answer/comment has the correct outlook.

Answer (score 2):

The performance should be trivial between the 2. However, you shouldn't be concerned with that. Your prepared statement is much more secure.

Your direct query would allow what is known as a SQL injection attack if `$id` comes from any user input - query string, form, etc.

Comment: Agreed. Performance difference ought to be very small.In case Daniel's statement didn't make sense, the 2nd method of doing the query is dangerous should your $id come straight from external input. It could be subjected to hacking attempts.

Comment: Actually, I have my input secured by this function:
`code` function secureString($input) {
    $mysqli=DB::cxv();
    $input=$mysqli->real_escape_string($input);
    $mysqli->close();
    $input=htmlentities($input,null,'UTF-8');
    return str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $input);
}
`code`
DB::cxv() is my mysqli connection!!!

Comment: @CvetomirLazarov - its not clear from your code which still is a security risk - thats a costly function as well.

Comment: Do prepared statements secure my input 100%?

Comment: @CvetomirLazarov yes as long as your sql statement is a straight string.

Comment: So if anyone enters ' OR 1=1, that would hurt my code? (SQLi)

Comment: as the concatenated string, yes.

Comment: What would you recommend me in order to prevent such problems with SQL Injection?

Comment: @CvetomirLazarov use prepared statements.

Comment: I started using prepared statements for the PDO extension. That gives me the opportunity to catch errors and use the fetching algorithm to loop through a multidimensional array of elements, grabbed from the database.